# Apache not respecting "RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]" when requesting javascript resource?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

this is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

if I go to `/mytheme/js/jquery.js` directly in my browser, I get index.php content, but if I add it as a script on a webpage like `<script type="text/javascript" src="/mytheme/js/jquery.js"></script>` I get a 200 empty response.

I am using a cheap shared hosting so not sure what their apache config is.

Comment: I am assuming, this is an actually physically existing file? In that case, the shown rewriting configuration should not affect it _at all_, because it explicitly checks whether what was requested does _not_ map onto any existing file or directory, before the rule is applied.

Comment: Which in turn could also mean, that you simply got the path wrong perhaps? That would explain why you’d get the index.php content.

Comment: there are no files on that server, only index.php. and if the file did exist, it would have the same behavior regardless of accessed directly or if embedded in a script. I edited the url to confirm it is not a wordpress site. and the url is exactly the same. I can see it in chrome devtool tab. it literally has different behavior when accessed directly vs embedded

Comment: So if the rewriting did not work in the second case, then that should rather get you a 404. Maybe verify first of all, by disabling your rewriting, and then calling any arbitrary fake URL, that the hoster does not have a messed-up setup that responds with a 200 in such cases. If that is _not_ the case, then I would assume that the rewrite works in both cases. Then it would be time to look at what exactly your index.php is doing.

Comment: my index.php is just "echo 'hello';" and I have an index.html which has some scripts. only those 2 files are o the server. the problem only occurs in the browser. if I use curl or go directly I can see "hello". but if it's embedded I get status 200 content length 0

Comment: On a local machine, I’d enable rewrite logging, and check what is going on internally. That probably won’t be possible on a cheap hosting platform, so I’d try to set up the same system locally, and see if the error can be reproduced there.

Comment: I just tried on my local machine with the same index.php and htaccess and I dont get the error, only on the cheap shared hosting

Comment: "the problem only occurs in the browser" - Make sure you are not seeing a cached response - check the network traffic in the browser dev tools and clear your cache. The cache could explain why you see a different response between direct requests and scripted requests in the page.

Comment: im pretty sure its not cached. I have cache disabled in dev tools and tried in incognito and the network tab headers doesn't say it's from the cache. also the cache should reset if I go to the url directly, yet it doesn't change the behavior at all.